# Where is the Go routine leak?

Tags: google-app-engine, concurrency, go

I'm trying to run several tasks concurrently and return immediately if there is any error without to wait for all of the routines  to return. The code looks as below. I've stripped out the noise to make it easier to digest but I can post the full code if the leak is not obvious. 
It's worth to note that I'm deploying this on google app engine. I can't reproduce the leak on my machine but when I replace the concurrency after `// Consume the results` comment the app is working fine, though I don't understand why because the code looks correct to me.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"
import "errors"

func main() {
    indexes := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
    devCh := make(chan int, 7)
    stopCh := make(chan struct{})
    errCh := make(chan error, 7)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    go func() {
        for _, sub := range indexes {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(sub int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                // some code which creates other
                // wait groups and spans other go routines
                // handle errors
                if sub == 99 { // unreachable 
                    errCh <- errors.New("new error")

                }
            }(sub)
            select {
            // If there is any error we better stop the
            // loop
            case <-stopCh:
                return
            default:
            }
            devCh <- sub
        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(devCh)
    }()
    // Consume the results
    var results []int
    var wt sync.WaitGroup
    wt.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wt.Done()
        for s := range devCh {
            results = append(results, s)
        }
        return
    }()
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        wt.Wait()
        close(done)
    }()

L:
    for {
        select {
        case err := <-errCh:
            fmt.Printf("error was %v", err)
            close(stopCh)
            return
        case <-done:
            break L
        default:
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("all done, %v", results)
}
```

Edit: added some working code.

Edit: added code closer to the real code which may explain the need of the for loop.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"
import "errors"

func main() {
    indexes := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
    indexesString := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    devChS := make(chan string, 1000)

    devCh := make(chan int, 7)
    stopCh := make(chan struct{})
    errCh := make(chan error, 7)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    go func() {
        for _, sub := range indexes {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(sub int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                // some code which creates other
                // wait groups and spans other go routines
                // handle errors
                if sub == 99 { // unreachable
                    errCh <- errors.New("new error")

                }
                wg.Add(1)
                go func(sub int) {
                    defer wg.Done()
                    for _, s := range indexesString {
                        devChS <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", s, sub)

                    }

                    return
                }(sub)
            }(sub)
            select {
            // If there is any error we better stop the
            // loop
            case <-stopCh:
                return
            default:
            }
            devCh <- sub
        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(devCh)
        close(devChS)
    }()
    // Consume the results
    var results = struct {
        integers []int
        strings  []string
    }{}
    var wt sync.WaitGroup
    wt.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wt.Done()
        for s := range devCh {
            results.integers = append(results.integers, s)
        }
        return
    }()
    wt.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wt.Done()
        for s := range devChS {
            results.strings = append(results.strings, s)
        }
        return
    }()
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        wt.Wait()
        close(done)
    }()

L:
    for {
        select {
        case err := <-errCh:
            fmt.Printf("error was %v", err)
            close(stopCh)
            return
        case <-done:
            break L
        default:
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("all done, can return the results: %v", results)
}
```

Comment: That `done` channel gets created and closed within 3 lines. Its also the way you break out of your infinite loop. Perhaps you should review its use?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I close the channel so that select can break. It breaks on a closed channel, isn't it ?

Comment: @Simon Whitehead Here is a snippet which proves that it works. http://play.golang.org/p/hJg1fbfO5d

Comment: I wasn't debating that it worked .. I was raising a concern about your use of it. It seems completely redundant.

Comment: How is that? I don't see any way to exit the loop and still return on errorCh without to wait for all the go routines to return.

Comment: You don't want to loop on a `select{}` with `default:`; if you drop the default, it will wait for communication to happen without occupying the CPU. I think App Engine has `GOMAXPROCS=1`, so if your machine doesn't have it, this may matter.

Comment: Design-wise, you can start a fixed set of tasks and collect results and errors with as little as one `go` statement in a loop, and a `for` loop collecting results/errors with a blocking select on a `chan struct { result int, err error }` until it gets to the expected count of items. If you have additional needs, it is still probably possible to get by with less than (4 `go`s + 2 `WaitGroup`s + 2 non-blocking `select`s + 3 `chan`s).

Comment: (If there are app-specific reasons all of those pieces truly are necessary, you have a complicated situation and may need a consultant, not just SO.)

Comment: @twotwotwo I'm not sure what "truly necessary" means but I would be surprised if you can reproduce the same results with one statement in a loop. The idea is basically to return as soon as there is an error on any go routine. That means that the error should be broadcasted to all the go routines including the "main" one otherwise new go routines are launched  from the loop while you "wait".

Comment: @twotwotwo btw the question is if there is any go routine leak. I think it's pretty straightforward after all and shouldn't require "consultancy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tl;dr*: A loop that does nothing but repeat a non-blocking check until it succeeds can cause hard-to-diagnose trouble (at a minimum, it can overuse CPU); using a blocking check can fix it.

I'm not all that sure about the details of your case; I wrote a loop like yours that consistently hangs with "process took too long" on the Playground, but when I run it locally it does complete.

As I commented, I'd aim for a simpler design, too.

---

[Go only has limited pre-emption of running goroutines](http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#preemption): the running thread only yields control to the goroutine scheduler when a blocking operation (an like I/O or channel op or waiting to take a lock) happens.

So with `GOMAXPROCS=1`, if the (one) running thread starts looping, nothing else will necessarily get a chance to run.

A `for { select { ...default: } }` can therefore start a loop checking for items in a channel but never give up control of the main thread so that another goroutine can write an item. Other code gets to run anyway when when `GOMAXPROCS` is over 1, but not when it's 1 as it is on App Engine (or the Playground). The behavior depends not only on `GOMAXPROCS`, but on which goroutine happens to run first, which isn't necessarily defined.

To avoid that situation, remove the `default:` so the `select` is a blocking operation that yields to the scheduler when it can't receive an item, allowing other code to run. You can generalize this to other cases where you might loop doing a nonblocking check; any of them could keep resources busy constantly rechecking when a blocking call would not. When `GOMAXPROCS>1` or the runtime's limited preemption saves you, polling (as repeated checking is called) can still consume more CPU than blocking.

For example, this fails with "process took too long" [on the Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/DWwfPd-Xqk), though annoyingly it completes reliably on my machine:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})
    go func() { c <- struct{}{} }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
            fmt.Println("success")
            return
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

I can't tell if there are other problems, but the hang for a pattern similar to the sample is noteworthy.

Comment: This seems to be the answer through the change doesn't make much sense to me as the for loop is definitely not starving the resources(i.e is cheap). Some networking code would also make use of such loops but maybe I just get this wrong.

Comment: One run through the loop is cheap, but it never yields to the scheduler so other code can send an item for it to pick up, so it ends up an infinite loop. I don't have a source handy, but in networking code, you'll tend to make a blocking call (in that case often just `Dial()`/`Read()`/`Write()`) that yields to the scheduler and lets other goroutines do other work.

Comment: This may be a bit too much but is there any way that I could have "detected" this issue without to actually know the internals/behaviour of the scheduler ?

Comment: I can't think of a trivial way to catch it here, no.

Comment: Updated answer slightly: I get hangs on the Playground still but, interestingly, not seeing it on my machine. I think it's because it depends not only on `GOMAXPROCS` but what code happens to run first, but not certain.